# Is there any way to rename the values I get from this API?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I want to rename the values I get from this external API in my `<span>{{stats.team.name}}</span`.

Right now it outputs every club name like this:

Manchester City FC
Manchester United FC
Wolverhampton Wanderers FC

I would like to make the name shorter and have it like this instead:

Man City
Man Utd
Wolves

Is it possible to do that in any simple way?

My HTML:

```
<div v-for="stats in tableStats" v-bind:key="stats.tableStats">
  <span>{{stats.team.name}}</span
</div>
```

API Call:

```
<script>

import axios from 'axios'

export default {

    data () {
    return {
      tableStats: null
    }
  },

    mounted () {
    axios.get('https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/PL/standings', {
        headers: {
            'X-Auth-Token': 'mytoken',
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
    })
      .then(response => (this.tableStats = response.data.standings[0].table))
  }
}

</script>
```

JSON:

```
"table": [
            {
                "position": 1,
                "team": {
                    "id": 65,
                    "name": "Manchester City FC",
                },
                "playedGames": 19,
                "form": "W,W,W,W,W",
                "won": 12,
                "draw": 5,
                "lost": 2,
                "points": 41,
                "goalsFor": 36,
                "goalsAgainst": 13,
                "goalDifference": 23
            },
```

Comment: how about adding short names from backend to each team name ? so you could bind accordingly

Comment: I haven't made the API so I can't change or add to it in any way I think?

Comment: my bad ... sorry didnt thought it as an external api ... you could modify the response data as you want , could you update how `stats` structure would look as .... Eugene as mentioned a way down

Comment: The API has a `team` resource that includes `shortName`. You would probably need to fetch this as well for each team - could be cached locally

Answer (score 2):

The API includes a `team` resource that includes `shortName`. You would need to fetch the individual team info separately using the teams resource url.

```
https://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/{id}
```

In your example using the id of 65 for Man City

```
https://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/65
```

Comment: Oh it does! Didn't know that, that's great. Is there any way to do it without fetching for all 20 teams?

Comment: I played around with this but I think I have to try another solution. I'm creating a league table which gets updated automatically by the external API so I guess I have to modify the club names from the response data in some way, not sure how tho..

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this? `.then(function(response) {
          if(response.data.standings[0].table.team.name === 'Manchester City FC') response = 'Man City';
      })`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a predefined map of short names and add a computed property in your Vue component to match long names with short ones.

Comment: Hm, how would you make that change apply to the <span>{{stats.team.name}}</span? I'm creating a league table which gets updated automatically by the external API.

Comment: @Chrilla Create `tableStatsNormalized` computed property which will return short names based on original names and mapping table long->short. Then use it in a template like `<div v-for="stats in tableStatsNormalized" v-bind:key="stats.tableStats">
  <span>{{stats.team.name}}</span
</div>`. Of course, you need to know all club names beforehand to create a mapping table.

Comment: Okay! But wouldn't that just list every team in the same order from top to bottom all the time? This table is updated automatically from the API so I need the teams to be able to move accordingly to that aswell. Sorry, I'm a real beginner when it comes to this, appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: That's why I'm saying about computed properties. They'll get updated every time when your data from API changes. Vue documentation about reactivity system and computed properties is a good start to grasp the idea.